# In iOS cross launching Uber app when longitude and latitude not available

Tags: uber-api

Is it possible to pass drop off location by cross launching Uber app when longitude and latitude are not available ?

For example, if I know location coordinates, my dropoff parameters are:

```
dropoff[latitude]
dropoff[longitude]
dropoff[nickname]
dropoff[formatted_address]
```

Sample URL:

```
uber://?client_id=<client_id>&action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff%5Blatitude%5D=37.621313&dropoff%5Blongitude%5D=-122.378955&dropoff%5Bnickname%5D=San%20Francisco%20Airport&dropoff%5Bformatted_address%5D=San%20Francisco,%20CA%2094128,%20United%20States
```

Everything works great. See attached screenshot:

[Drop off Destination correctly populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weHal.png)

What if I dont have longitude and latitude ? My dropoff parameters is only nickname:

```
dropoff[nickname]
```

Sample URL:

```
uber://?client_id=<client_id>&action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff%5Bnickname%5D=300%20el%20Camino%20real,%20Sunnyvale,%20ca
```

I would expect in absence of coordinates the nickname is used as a query (same as what used when coordinates are available). But the destination is empty in this case.

[Drop off Destination is emtpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR0H7.png)

Is this an expected behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

Including only the dropoff nickname does not set the dropoff location. The latitude and longitude are required for setting the location, while the nickname/address are used for visual purposes.

You can use Apple's `CLGeocoder` class to do geocoding on your nickname and get a location coordinate to pass in the deeplink.